# Order email not sending, I'm being asked to edit my crontab but I don't know how

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron, crontab

I have a problem with the Order Confirmation emails not sending, all the others appear to be sending just not the Order confirmation ones.

I've installed AOE scheduler, and it's indicating that there is No Heartbeat task found and asks that I edit my cronab

```
sudo crontab -u new2magento -e
```

and add the following configuration

```
 * * * * * ! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
* * * * * ! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default
```

I'm fairly new to magento and could really do with some help finding exactly where I have to add the configuration

Answer (score 0):

This will depend on your hosting provider. Im assuming you dont have your own dedicated server or this is something you should already know. If your on cPanel there is a button somewhere for it. I dont use cPanel though. I use virtualmin and its under the webmin and look for the task acheduler

Comment: yeah it uses cpanel, there is a secton called cron jobs, but I don't really have any knowledge of what to do from there

Comment: Its asking you to set a cronjob with the command of test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always

For every second of every hour of every day but this is hard on your system I would recommend it to run every 5 or 15 minutes to help reserve server resources

Comment: so do I just copy and paste those lines as separate jobs and set them to every 5 mins?

Comment: Yes or go back to the installation instructions and setup the correct cronjob for the installation itself

Comment: so copy ad paste  `* * * * * ! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always` ? or `-e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always`

Comment: Copy and paste each command starting at the test part the stars tell you the time it wants you to have it scheduled

Comment: I've added them as cron jobs in cpanel like you said but I'm still getting the same message

Comment: Did ypu try running the cron job manually to see if you get errors?

Comment: Also you really should set up magentos installation cron job. This is what sends system emails amongst other functions

Comment: Sorry one last thing. If ypur system has a maintenance.flag file for the cron job to test it means your system is in maintenance mode and will not be able to sell products or even be visited.

Comment: so how do I deal with that?

Comment: Deal with which part the installation cron job or the cron job its asking for

Comment: ok how do I run a cron job manually?

Comment: When u created the cron job isn there a button that says run cron job now

Comment: no just edit or delete

Comment: Ok im on my phone give me a few and ill get you the full thing to run the cron job. Do you have ssh access

Comment: thanks, I'm getting an email indicating they have failed, it looks like the cron tasks are being scheduled in AOE but are just sitting there pending

Comment: `! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default`

Comment: If i add these as cron jobs in cpanel `! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always
! test -e /home/new2magento/public_html/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/new2magento/public_html/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default` i get a message x-powered-By: php/5.4.45 content type: text/html